# Pattern-match against Any => List[Any] => List[Long]

Tags: scala

Using Scala I am trying to pattern match against a class that returns a value type of `Any` to pull out any `List[Any]` and pattern match against `List[Long]` and `List[Double]`.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Running scala 2.11

```scala
case class Accumulator (
    name: Option[String],
    value: Option[Any]
)

def bar[T <: Any](value: T): Unit = {
    val listOfAny = value.asInstanceOf[List[Any]]
    val listOfTypes = listOfAny.map(x => x.getClass.getSimpleName).toSet

    listOfTypes.size match {
        case 1 => listOfTypes.head match {
            case "Long" => println("Long list")
            case "Double" => println("Double list")
            case _ => Unit
        }
        case _ => Unit //Probably throw an error log
    }
}

def foo(accumulator: Accumulator): Unit = {
    accumulator match {
        case Accumulator(_, Some(value)) => value match {
            case v if v.isInstanceOf[List[_]] => bar(v)
            case _ => Unit
        }
        case _ => Unit
    }
}


//Should print out "Long List"
foo(Accumulator(None, Some(List(1L, 2L, 3L))))
//Should print out "Double List"
foo(Accumulator(None, Some(List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))))
```

Edit:

Was able to clean up the string matching with stable identifiers

```scala
case class Accumulator (
    name: Option[String],
    value: Option[Any]
)

def bar[T <: Any](value: T): Unit = {
    val listOfAny = value.asInstanceOf[List[Any]]
    val listOfTypes = listOfAny.map(x => x.getClass).toSet

    listOfTypes.size match {
        case 1 => 
            val headType: Class[_] = listOfTypes.head

            // Stable identifiers
            val ClassOfLong: Class[java.lang.Long] = classOf[java.lang.Long]
            val ClassOfDouble: Class[java.lang.Double] = classOf[java.lang.Double]

            headType match {
                case ClassOfLong => 
                    val result: Long = listOfAny.asInstanceOf[List[Long]].sum
                    println(s"Long List sum: $result")
                case ClassOfDouble =>
                    val result: Double = listOfAny.asInstanceOf[List[Double]].sum
                    println(s"Double List sum: $result")
                case _ => Unit
        }
        case _ => Unit //Probably throw an error log
    }
}

def foo(accumulator: Accumulator): Unit = {
    accumulator match {
        case Accumulator(_, Some(value)) => value match {
            case v if v.isInstanceOf[List[_]] => bar(v)
            case _ => Unit
        }
        case _ => Unit
    }
}


//Should print out "Long List sum: 6"
foo(Accumulator(None, Some(List(1L, 2L, 3L))))
//Should print out "Double List sum: 6.0"
foo(Accumulator(None, Some(List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))))
```

Comment: A more elegant way would be not using `Any`. Also, your snippet doesn't compile

Comment: @Dima sorry about that, I fixed up the script was missing two vals and an Accumulator wrapper. Not using `Any` is not an option because it is what's returned from a class that is not mine. I'm actually expecting an AccumulableInfo from Spark.

Comment: It still doesn't compile. `Unit` is the name of a type, not a value.
Also, I am not sure what you mean by "elegant". There is _nothing_ "elegant" about `Any`. You have to cast it to a real type to be able to do anything useful with it.

Comment: @Dima I don't know what to say. I literally copied and pasted the above into my scala terminal and it compiles/runs just fine. This is not an argument about if `Any` is elegant, it's simply a constraint that I am facing. I rather not have to use `Any` as well. The entire point of this exercise is to cast it into a real type as an end goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case class Accumulator (
    name: Option[String],
    value: Option[Any]
)

def bar[T <: Any](value: T): Unit = {
    val listOfAny = value.asInstanceOf[List[Any]]
    val listOfTypes = listOfAny.map(x => x.getClass).toSet

    listOfTypes.size match {
        case 1 => 
            val headType: Class[_] = listOfTypes.head

            // Stable identifiers
            val ClassOfLong: Class[java.lang.Long] = classOf[java.lang.Long]
            val ClassOfDouble: Class[java.lang.Double] = classOf[java.lang.Double]

            headType match {
                case ClassOfLong => 
                    val result: Long = listOfAny.asInstanceOf[List[Long]].sum
                    println(s"Long List sum: $result")
                case ClassOfDouble =>
                    val result: Double = listOfAny.asInstanceOf[List[Double]].sum
                    println(s"Double List sum: $result")
                case _ => Unit
        }
        case _ => Unit //Probably throw an error log
    }
}

def foo(accumulator: Accumulator): Unit = {
    accumulator match {
        case Accumulator(_, Some(value)) => value match {
            case v if v.isInstanceOf[List[_]] => bar(v)
            case _ => Unit
        }
        case _ => Unit
    }
}


//Should print out "Long List sum: 6"
foo(Accumulator(None, Some(List(1L, 2L, 3L))))
//Should print out "Double List sum: 6.0"
foo(Accumulator(None, Some(List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the lists are not empty and all the elements are of the same type, you can match both the returned object and the first element in the list. Something like this

```
def surprise(): Any = Random.nextInt(3) match {
  case 0 => List(1L, 2L, 3L)
  case 1 => List(0.5, 1.5, 2.5)
  case _ => "foo"
}

0 to 10 foreach { _ =>
  surprise() match {
    case l @ List(_: Long, _*) =>
      println(s"Longs: $l")
    case l @ List(_: Double, _*) =>
      println(s"Doubles: $l")
    case x =>
      println(s"Something else: $x")
  }
}
```

Output:

```
"""
Something else: foo
Something else: foo
Longs: List(1, 2, 3)
Doubles: List(0.5, 1.5, 2.5)
Doubles: List(0.5, 1.5, 2.5)
Doubles: List(0.5, 1.5, 2.5)
Doubles: List(0.5, 1.5, 2.5)
Doubles: List(0.5, 1.5, 2.5)
Something else: foo
Longs: List(1, 2, 3)
Something else: foo
"""
```

Comment: This is similar to the Dima's answer of which was deleted. One issue that I am facing is that since it is coming in as an `Any` type, I am not guaranteed to have a list of all one type or I may get an empty list. I rather not make assumptions and handle those edge cases.